# does awk support quantifiers - i want [0-9]{6,6}

Tags: regex, awk

gawk doesn't seem to match six digit fields - or n digit fields using the {n,m} quantifiers

It does match [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] ok.

Doesn't seem to support \d\d\d\d\d\d either.

Do i need to turn on extended reg ex, or does it just not support that.

Tnx

Answer (score 10):

You need to specify the "`--re-interval`" (or "`-W re-interval`") flag to take advantage of this behavior.

```
echo 12345 | gawk --re-interval '/[0-9]{5}/{print}{}'
12345
echo 12345 | gawk --re-interval '/[0-9]{6}/{print}{}'
<no output>
```

Answer (score 4):

Expanding minimally on Pax's response, `--posix` also enables this behavior.  Also, you are correct that gawk does not support the character class escapes (like `\d`) but it does support the `[[:digit:]]` syntax.

Comment: sorry, I didn't see that you answered the second part about escape characters also.  thanks